# detect how a button was pressed in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to detect how a button was pressed?

- mouse clicked //mouse event
- highlighted via tab then enter key //keypress event
- touched (mobile phones) //touch event

Is there a short javascript way to detect this? Or do I need to add event listeners for click, enter, and touch? I want to get data for form submits. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "short javascript way"?

Comment: I can't guess why you need it. What is purpose?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can handle for

> highlighted via tab then enter key //keypress event

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    console.log(e);

    // Screen Positions returns 0 on enter
    if( e.screenX == 0 && e.screenY == 0 ) {
        alert('Enter');
    }
    else if( e.type == "click" ) {
        alert('click');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/ymr0ttsq/1/) Ofcause rest you will detect easily.

Comment: I only need the touch left but so far this is awesome! Can you tell me why Screen Positions returns 0 on enter? Is it native javascript behavior?

Comment: @Deadpool the event could happen at exactly that location when the element is pressed or click. So its returning (0, 0) on enter.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, 'enter' and 'touch' also trigger 'click'.

I think it's safe to add an event listener to 'click' to handle all your required events.

try here: https://jsfiddle.net/wvv2v8r2/

```
<input type="submit" value="test click" />

$('input').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: I was shocked that enter triggered click!?!? I tested it after reading your answer. +1

Comment: They all trigger click, but weren't you asking how to detect which is which?

Comment: @Whathaveyoutried yeah I just gave a +1 not the correct answer because I learned something new?

Comment: @Deadpool, yeah, why not :)  because the duty of a button is to be 'clicked'

Answer (score 0):

click and touch you can handle with help of the onclick 
but for highlighted via tab then enter key you have to a separate code

Answer (score 0):

All `mousedown`, `click` and `key press` event will trigger the `click` event only. No need to have three different event listeners.

If you have all three event handlers, then the order of execution will differ.

On `keypress`, at first `keypress` will fire then `click`.

If you have `mousedown`, then at first `mousedown` then `click` will trigger.

```
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  console.log("click");
}, false);

document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  console.log("mousedown");
}, false);

document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if(keyCode===13) {
     console.log("enter pressed");
  }
}, false);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/zukuxubise/1/edit?html,js,console,output)**

In the demo you will notice that, all refer to the `click` event at the end.

So it's best to just go with click event itself.